# How to get nested elements with JacksonXmlRootElement?

Tags: java, xml, spring, api, jackson

I am using Java/Spring

I have XML like this:

```
 <Transfer> 
 <Data>
     ... 
 </Data>
 <Transfer>
```

and I just need to access to XML element "Data" for my model, like:
`@JacksonXmlRootElement (localName = "Data")`

Is it possible without additional wrapper class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friendly reminder to everyone: please don't mix-up JAXB with JacksonXML. All my problems were from there.

Just add an additional model, like in code below:

```
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Transfer")
public class WrapperClass{

   @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Data")
   public MyClass myClas;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible without additional wrapper class?

Yes, it is possible if you read the xml tag you are interested with the [`XMLStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) class directly pointing the involved tag, be aware you have to manually place the `XMLStreamReader` reader to the correct tag:

```
//the simplest class, the classname is the same of the <Data> tag so no need for
//@JacksonXmlRootElement (localName = "Data")
public class Data {}

XMLInputFactory f = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader sr = f.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(xml));
XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
sr.nextTag();
sr.nextTag(); //<-- pointing the <Data> tag
Data data = mapper.readValue(sr, Data.class);
sr.close();
```